# Backend is not running after post request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a stripe checkout project but was stuck when I found that the URL is changing after clicking my plan button but was not able to provide that button value to the backend.
Here is my code for front-end where I am doing this :

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { isAuth } from "../helpers/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./Pricing.module.scss";
import ScriptTag from "react-script-tag";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

const PUBLISHABLE_KEY =
  "pk_test_453765834";

export const Pricing = () => {
  const buttonValue = useRef();

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const setBtnValue = (e) => {
    buttonValue.current = e.target.value;
  };
  const checkoutHandler = async (e) => {
    const btnValue = buttonValue.current;
    const stripe = await loadStripe(PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
    console.log(btnValue);
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/checkout", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        btnValue,
      }),
    })
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .then(({ sessionID }) => stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionID }))
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.error.message);
      });
  };
return (
<div>
  <ScriptTag
    isHydrating={true}
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"
  />
<form onSubmit = {checkoutHandler}>
        <button
          value= 'price_bdsahfbadshb'
          type="submit"
          className="btn"
          name="product"
          onClick={setBtnValue}
        >
          Upgrade Now
        </button>
</div>
)
}
```

Here is my route in the backend for receiving this value :

```
router.post('/checkout' , async(req,res) => {
    const product = req.body;
    console.log(product);
    }
```

But in the above code, I am receiving this req.body as empty, and sometimes my backend run first then the front-end. Please check this problem anyone and guide me.

Comment: does node js print something to console after the call?

Comment: nope , it doesn't print anything

Comment: change `console.log(product);` to `console.log(req);` on the backend and try calling it again, also,  try calling your backend with postman, and see what happens

Comment: I did't recieve anything as my backend isn't running . I am not able to post the request I think

Comment: Check my react code here : https://pastebin.com/RAZpbVxr and my route code : 
https://pastebin.com/ivrgSn2i

Comment: your server isn't running? or it stops after the call? what kind of error do your receive? it would be helpful if you send me your pastebin of your main server file at your backend

Comment: I found out , the await loadstripe line is blocking the post request . Here is my main server.js: https://pastebin.com/e3F9iytL

Answer (score 0):

You should check your network tab and look for this post request there. Check the name value and see if it is same thing with the value name for the response. And also the buttonValue is the value name in the backend and you never assign it to receive the request body in the backend. Like this:
`buttonValue: req.body.buttonValue`

Comment: Check my react code here : https://pastebin.com/RAZpbVxr and my route code : https://pastebin.com/ivrgSn2i . Please format it man , I need help . And I didn't have any post request in network tab , it seems something is blocking is request to go to backend

Comment: And I see only one request in my backend which is http://localhost:3000/pricing?product=price_#PRICECODE

Comment: I found out the blockage in my code, the await loadStripe line is blocking the further processing in the code that is why the request is not being at the backend.

Comment: You should always track request with network tab. It will reduce your time for debugging. I'm glad you solve the issue

Comment: nope , it didn't solved , on more hustling I found an issue : Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute .  I think this might be a problem in blockage

Comment: Is your code now working fine?

Comment: Nope , URL changes not the screen and the request doesn't go to backend . I solved the cookie issue  but still same thing .